# appium inspector 'invalid session id' to NoSuchDriverError

Tags: android, session, automation, appium

I'm constantly getting an Error when trying to Start a Session using Appium inspector. I tried restting and re-starting the device but I'm still facing the same issue. The issue once got resolved when I unistalled and re-installed the Appium inspector, however this solution isn't feisable apparently.

Json Config Capabilities (Appium inspector)

```
{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appium:platformVersion": "12",
  "appium:deviceName": "Pixel 7 API 31 (S)",
  "appium:app": "D:\\Automation_code\\TestAutomation\\test\\app\\Android_app_demo-244.apk",
  "appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2"
}
```

Command prompt ERROR

```
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)] Got response with status 404: {"sessionId":"317d63c4-1b69-44c6-a43b-6ad848e5c6da","value":{"error":"invalid session id","message":"The session identified by 317d63c4-1b69-44c6-a43b-6ad848e5c6da is not known","stacktrace":"io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: The session identified by 317d63c4-1b69-44c6-a43b-6ad848e5c6da is not known\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:54)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:259)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:253)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:77)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:3...
[W3C] Matched W3C error code 'invalid session id' to NoSuchDriverError
[HTTP] <-- GET /session/3ca9865d-93b8-4e32-a9b5-d3f3e481d007/source 404 9 ms - 3691
```

[Commpand Prompt output Appium inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J89aH.png)

Full Error

```html
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)] Encountered internal error running command: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: The session identified by 317d63c4-1b69-44c6-a43b-6ad848e5c6da is not known
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:54)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:259)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:253)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:77)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]
[HTTP] <-- GET /session/3ca9865d-93b8-4e32-a9b5-d3f3e481d007/screenshot 404 111 ms - 3691
[HTTP]
[HTTP] --> GET /session/3ca9865d-93b8-4e32-a9b5-d3f3e481d007/window/rect
[HTTP] {}
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)] Calling AppiumDriver.getWindowRect() with args: ["3ca9865d-93b8-4e32-a9b5-d3f3e481d007"]
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)] Matched '/window/current/size' to command name 'getWindowSize'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)] Proxying [GET /window/current/size] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/session/317d63c4-1b69-44c6-a43b-6ad848e5c6da/window/current/size] with no body
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)] Got response with status 404: {"sessionId":"317d63c4-1b69-44c6-a43b-6ad848e5c6da","value":{"error":"invalid session id","message":"The session identified by 317d63c4-1b69-44c6-a43b-6ad848e5c6da is not known","stacktrace":"io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: The session identified by 317d63c4-1b69-44c6-a43b-6ad848e5c6da is not known\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:54)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:259)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:253)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:77)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:3...
[W3C] Matched W3C error code 'invalid session id' to NoSuchDriverError
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)] Encountered internal error running command: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: The session identified by 317d63c4-1b69-44c6-a43b-6ad848e5c6da is not known
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:54)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:259)
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@e71f (3ca9865d)]     at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:253)
```

Trying to run Appium inspector without facing the Invalid session ID error
Executed the following command in command prompt
`appium -p 4724 --allow-cors`
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w3Nk.png)